# Equivalent of sha1 in db2

Tags: encryption, db2, sha1

I've stored password in mysql using SHA1 encryption And I have migrated my DB from mysql to DB2.

From Db2, how can I fetch record from Db2?

```
Select * from table where name = 'user' and password = sha1('123456')
```

But it generates error in db2. How can I check the login for the existing details?

Comment: from doing a search for ["DB2 sha1" on google](http://www.google.com/search?q=DB2+sha1), it appears that you'll have to make your own udf for sha1 that.

Comment: U mean I need to create user defined function for sha1() function?

Answer (score 0):

If the original app contains only a few references to sha1() in the SQL statements, you could switch them a similar function in DB2, such as ENCRYPT() http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004211.html.

Comment: Unfortunately this would require changing the passwords or temporarily capturing them on the MySQL side, since DB2's ENCRYPT() is based on RC2 and MD5, not SHA1. Your other option, as Dan points out, is to roll your own SHA1 function in DB2, with Java probably being the easiest option. Here's a relatively short sample implementation of the SHA1 part, but not the UDF part: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_simple_class_to_compute_sha_1_hash.xml

Answer (score 0):

Now you have a [HASH function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2oc?topic=functions-hash)

```
SELECT HEX(HASH('Charlie at IBM',1)) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1; 
D6E42303462491FC696EAC53C1B086A5034735A7
```